# How to get nested relational models in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models.

1. Post
2. Comment
3. Reply

The relation between the model:

1. Post has many Comment
2. Comment has many Reply

I want to get all the replies of all the comments of a single post. Is there any query to get all the replies of a post?

Comment: `$post->load('comments.replies');` where `comments` is a relationship on `Post` model and `replies` is a relationship on `Comment` model

Comment: @ArunAS you were 5 seconds faster than me :))

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships and https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections you should have a look at the docs

Comment: @ArunAS I saw the answer, but `$post->load('comments.replies');` is the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Eager loading to get the nested relationship:

```
Post::with('comments.replies')->get();
```

Comment: Why eager and not lazy?

Comment: If by lazy you mean *lazy eager* loading, they both do the same functionality, so its up for the Programmer to decide which to use.